# Signal Comparisons: "Orthogonal functions"

Tags: signal

When comparing two vectors, if the angle between them is 90 degrees then they would be seen as orthogonal and Cn= 0 where Cn is the correlation between these two vectors representing a signal.

What if we had two functions and wanted to compare their correlation. In this case under what conditions would Cn= 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a mathematics question, you should take a look at [Hilbert Spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) for a more detailed answer, but.

To define a space (e.g., the space of functions) you have to define an *inner product* between any two elements of the space into the scalars, which must [satisfy a few properties](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html), that basically guarantee linearity and uniqueness. This is the generalization of dot product from simple vector spaces, and shares all of its properties.

For the typical space of functions, the inner product commonly takes the following form (but other forms are possible):

$$ <f(x),g(x)> = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(y) g(y) dy } $$

Saying that two functions are orthogonal, just means that their inner product is zero.

Note that the correlation between two functions is not a function into the scalars (although its zero lag element is). For some definition of inner product, it can be made directly equivalent to the zero lag of the correlation.

Answer (score 0):

sin waves are orthogonal to

1) other sin waves, if each has a rational number period compared to the other, and the correlation occurs PRECISELY over the period; thus sin(17 t) and sin(14 t) are orthogonal if multiplied and integrated (correlated) over 1second exactly.

2) sins and cosines of the same frequency are orthogonal, **if** correlated over an integer # of periods.

Fourier Transform analysis has to deal with the fractional-period problem. "Windowing" is used in such a case.